# org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: index row requires more memory than default(8191)

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I am trying to use PostgreSQL in our existing project to improve the performance and make it friendly with JSON. I have done some research on the PostgreSQL and trying to integrate it into our application. But I am facing some problems when I am trying to insert the large json document into the table. It is working with small set of json document but fails with the large data. The following is the error dispalyed in the console when inserting the data.

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: index row requires 11936 bytes, maximum size is 8191
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2284)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2003)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:200)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:424)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeWithFlags(PgStatement.java:321)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeUpdate(PgStatement.java:297)
    at com.practice.PracticeClass.main(PracticeClass.java:28)
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: index row requires 11936 bytes, maximum size is 8191
```

## PracticeClass.java

```
package com.practice;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class PracticeClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        Connection c = null;
        Statement st = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
            c = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jsonbdb", "postgres", "admin");
            System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
            st = c.createStatement();
            String query = "create table IpauDeviceInfo(id serial, deviceinfo jsonb UNIQUE)";
            st.executeUpdate(query);
            System.out.println("Table created successfully");

            StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            strBuilder.append(**large_json_document**);

            String insertQuery = "insert into IpauDeviceInfo(\"deviceinfo\") values(" + strBuilder.toString() + ")";
            st.executeUpdate(insertQuery);
            System.out.println("inserted successfully");
            /*String upadteQuery = "update jsonbtab_unique set \"deviceinfo\" = jsonb_set(\"deviceinfo\", '{deviceId}', '\"SHARP-MX-Dev_10002\"', true) where \"deviceinfo\"-> 'deviceId' = '\"Brother_Dev_001\"'";
            st.executeUpdate(upadteQuery);*/
            ResultSet rs  = st.executeQuery("select (\"deviceinfo\") from IpauDeviceInfo");
            while(rs.next()) {
                System.out.println("count: " + rs.getFetchSize());
                System.out.println("rows: " + rs.getString("deviceinfo"));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.err.println(e.getClass().getName()+": "+e.getMessage());
            System.exit(0);
        } finally {
            c.close();
            st.close();
        }
    }
}
```

In the above error, It is saying memory is not sufficient to create an index. I am new to this Postgres. I am not creating any index when inserting the json document. I am thinking it is internally creating an index for the column.

Table creation:

```
Create table sample(id serial, info jsonb);
```

Could any tell me how to resolve this error or how to configure to increase the memory to insert large data.

Comment: It doesn't create any indices by itself. Check the database, you must have an index on the jsonb column for this error to appear somehow.

Comment: Thank you @SamiKuhmonen, but I did not create any index in the particular jsonb row. I checked the database in the PgAdmin-III, it is showing index(0).

Comment: Ok, then it's quite strange indeed. Never seen this happen, hope someone can shed light on it.

Comment: The `create table` as shown will not cause that error. I'm pretty sure there is an additional index somewhere. Can you share the code of `PracticeClass.java`

Comment: hello @a_horse_with_no_name, Please look into the edited question has Practice.calss.

Comment: You ***are*** creating an index on that column. `deviceinfo jsonb UNIQUE` defines a unique constraint on that column which will create an index.

Comment: Yes, Thank you. I got rid of this error.